# Can send data objects from client to server using the Pickle and socket modules in Python?

Tags: python, server, connection, client

I want to my client program to send objects to server. By searching the internet, in all the examples, I have seen data objects are sent by the server to the client, but I want to do the opposite. Below I am sharing both the client codes and the server code. I have been able to modify the socket client code, but I am having difficulty in modifying the server code. As, I am new to python programming and I am on a deadline, a help is greatly appreciated.

Here are the codes:

Server code::

```
import socket



def server_program():

    # get the hostname
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 5000  # initiate port no above 1024
    server_socket = socket.socket()  # get instance
    # look closely. The bind() function takes tuple as argument
    server_socket.bind((host, port))  # bind host address and port together

    # configure how many client the server can listen simultaneously
    server_socket.listen(2)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
    print("Connection from: " + str(address))
    while True:
        # receive data stream. it won't accept data packet greater than 1024 bytes
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
            # if data is not received break
            break
        print("from connected user: " + str(data))
        data = input(' -> ')
        conn.send(data.encode())  # send data to the client

    conn.close()  # close the connection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()
```

Here is the client code modified with pickle::

```
import socket
import pickle


def client_program():
    host = socket.gethostname()  # as both code is running on same pc
    port = 5000  # socket server port number

    client_socket = socket.socket()  # instantiate
    client_socket.connect((host, port))  # connect to the server

    message = input(" -> ")  # take input

    while message.lower().strip() != 'bye':
        client_socket.send(message.encode())  # send message
        #data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()  # receive response

        #print('Received from server: ' + data)  # show in terminal

        wastebin_attr = {1:"Wastebin_serial_number", 2:"Wastebin_type", 3:"Status" , 4:"Action", 5:"Zone", 6:"Latitude", 7:"Longitude"}
        mssg = pickle.dumps(wastebin_attr)
        print("from connected user: " + mssg)
        message = input(" -> ")  # again take input

    client_socket.close()  # close the connection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data from the client to the server using the pickle module:

```
data = pickle.dumps(data)
client_socket.send(data)
```

To receive the data on the servers end use:

```
data = conn.recv(1024)
data = pickle.loads(data)
```

You could also use this to send from server to client by switching the client_socket and conn parts

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting somewhere with it. Just instead of 'data' I am using 'mssg'. But there is another issue that have arise. On compilation I am getting the following error:    Sorry: IndentationError: unexpected indent (Test_server.py, line 23)

Comment: Python is picky on where the tabs go. Everything must be tabbed and spaced correctly otherwise it will not run.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did some research and I found it has something to do with spacings and tabs. I shall look into it. Thanks a lot.